# Kotlin: how to call a inline generic method with the type parameter of the class

Tags: java, kotlin, generics

I am trying to call an inline generic function

```
class Test<T> {

    fun foo() {
        val o = Other()
        o.bar<T>() //<-- Compilation error here: Cannot use T as a reified type parameter
    }
}

class Other {
    inline fun <reified K> bar() {
        val list = listOf<K>()
    }
}
```

Here class `Other` is a library class I cannot control. Please let me know how to call the method bar() with generic type parameter from the `Test` class.

Comment: Is there maybe an alternative function `bar()` which is not reified, but instead receives a `KClass`/`Class`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. `reified` parameters are always `inline` as well, which allows the compiler to pass the *literal* class argument to the function. That's why you can do `T::class` on `reified` parameters.

So you cannot pass an "unspecified" `T` to a `reified` function. Only literals that the compiler can inline.

Answer (score 1):

> o.bar() //<-- Compilation error here: Cannot use T as a reified type parameter

this error indicates that T is not reified type, meaning its type will be erased at runtime. Other.bar requires reified types because it will be inlined with it. There are not much you can do, only workaround I can suggest is below manual calling Other.bar with each known type used with Test class.

```
//you need to provide the type parameter to the function call
class Test<T>(private val clazz: Class<T>) {

    //this is a workaround function, it will allow for inlining with
    //specified type - making it possible to use reified type in a call to Other.bar()
    private inline fun <reified U> funnyBar(o: Other) {
        o.bar<U>()
    }

    fun foo() {
        val o = Other()

        //ugly but works, you will need to add each type used
        //with test in below when statement.
        when (clazz) {
            String::class.java -> funnyBar<String>(o)
            Int::class.java -> funnyBar<Int>(o)
            //...
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("add new type")
        }
    }
}


//other stays unchanged
class Other {
    inline fun <reified K> bar() {
        val list = listOf<K>()
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val test = Test(String::class.java)
    test.foo()

    val test2 = Test(Int::class.java)
    test2.foo()
}
```

you can find more on reified types here : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters