# How to deal with library inline generic functions with reified and allow dependency injection?

Tags: kotlin, generics, dependency-injection, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

I have a some library method, which I can't really change.

```
class Lib {
    inline fun <reified T> getSomething(): T {
        // ...
    }
}
```

It uses reified generic parameter to pass information about the generic return type. It sadly does not have a version with `KClass<T>` instead of `reified`.

I would like to make a class that wraps this library's funcionality to simplify the access to it and allows dependency injection so I can mock it and test classes that depend on it. I also have interface `Something` that restricts the generic parameter `T` in my app.

```
sealed interface Something {
    // ...
}

interface Wrapper {
    fun <T : Something> getSomething(): T
}

class LibWrapper : Wrapper {
    private val library = Lib()

    fun <T : Something> getSomething(): T {
        // ... it does some other stuff around as well
        val something = library.getSomething<T>()
        // ...
    }
}
```

This is obviously not working because the non-reified generics are only relevant at compile time. I tried several approaches unsuccessfuly:

1. **Propagating inline up into my code**

This is not possible because virtual members cannot be inline and also you cannot override non-inline with inline, so no dependency injection.

```
internal interface Wrapper {
    inline fun <reified T : Something> getSomething(): T
}

internal class LibWrapper : Wrapper {
    private val library = Lib()

    override inline fun <reified T : Something> getSomething(): T {
        // ...
        val something = library.getSomething<T>()
        // ...
    }
}
```

2. **Using `KClass<T>`**

This also does not work because `T` is still available only at compile time (I guess).

```
interface Wrapper {
    fun <T : Something> getSomething(type: KClass<out T>): T
}

class LibWrapper : Wrapper {
    private val library = Lib()

    override fun <T : Something> getSomething(type: KClass<out T>): T {
        // ...
        val something = library.getSomething<T>()
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

**So what should I do?** I know this is little bit of a duplicate of these to questions [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77167829/kotlin-how-to-call-a-inline-generic-method-with-the-type-parameter-of-the-class) [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60037849/kotlin-reified-generic-in-virtual-function), but I would like to expand on them by **asking about solution for this general problem.** I mean, I am sure that author of the library had his reasons for using reified and the answer "it is not possible" doesn't seem good enough, should I not do the dependecny injection then or not use generics at all here?

**I have a few ideas:**

Let's say I have two classes that implement `Something`

```
class A : Something {
    // ...
}

class B : Something {
    // ...
}
```

1. **Do a method for each type implementing `Something` interface**

I could wrap `A` and `B` each into a method of its own.

```
interface Wrapper {
    fun getA(): A
    fun getB(): B
}

class LibWrapper : Wrapper {
    private val library = Lib()

    override fun getA(): A {
        // ...
        val something = library.getSomething<A>()
        // ...
    }

    override fun getB(): B {
        // ...
        val something = library.getSomething<B>()
        // ...
    }
}
```

This is kinda tedious if the number of implementers of `Something` begins to grow and if the `Wrapper` methods share common code (u could extract that into another private method tho). I have about 8 methods like this provided by `Lib`, so even with having lets say 5 implementers of `Something` it pretty quickly grows to about 40 methods, which seems pretty excessive considering that all of them do pretty much the same thing. Also this kinda seems to defeat the whole purpose of generics if I have to implement each method separately.

2. **Map `KClass<T>` to `getSomething<T>()` by hand**

I can use `when` to make my own version of `getSomething` extension method on `Lib` that uses `KClass<T>` and calls corresponding `getSomething` method with concrete type. Then I can use the 2. approach above.

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun <T : Something> Lib.getSomething(type: KClass<out T>): T {
    return when(type) {
        A::class -> getSomething<A>() as T
        B::class -> getSomething<B>() as T
        else -> throw NotImplementedError()
    }
}
```

This shares similar issues as the approach above. It is little bit less code, but is bit more confusing since you have to rememeber to put a new case for each implementer inside this extension. Also it for some reason requires the `else` case even though the interface is `sealed` so it should be impossible to execute.

3. **Some entirely different approach/architecture?**

Should go about it in an entirely different way? My only constraints are that I would like dependency injection around the library and I (obviously) can't change the library methods. implementers of `Something` are `@Serializable data class` if it somehow helps.

**What approach should I go for?**

Comment: To be honest, the two posts you linked are the "solution for this general problem" already. There is really nothing you can do if there is no `KClass`/`Class` overload.I cannot think of a good reason why the library author does not provide such an overload. You should talk to them.

Comment: Actually, you can write your own version of `getSomething` that takes a `KClass` by just copying the implementation of `getSomething`, but I suppose it would be hard to maintain if the library frequently updates.

Comment: @Sweeper The library does something with the `@Serializable` annotation and it's a kotlin multiplatform library so I thought maybe that has something to do with it. Copying the implementation therefore would be also difficult because its multiplatform. I will try to raise the issue with authors of the library tho.

Comment: @Sweeper Indeed, the library had it already implemented. It was just not really straight forward so I missed it. Idk if you wanna do some sort of answer so I can accept it? Otherwise I'll answer myself after some time and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, there is really no reason for library not to have the `KClass` overload

In my case it was just hidden behind `SerializationStrategy` type, so I missed it. I had to pass `type.serializer()` instead of just `type`.